# multiply columns by a user defined variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a select statement working as shown below

```
$test = $pdo->query('Select col1, SUM(col2), SUM(col3), SUM(col3)*SUM(col2) from table group by col1');
```

I now want to multiply the sum of col2 so I have this line working

```
$test = $pdo->query('Select col1, SUM(col2)*100, SUM(col3), SUM(col3)*SUM(col2) from table group by col1');
```

However I want the user to be able to define the number in a form.  I have the form working and I have created a variable as shown below.

```
$custom = ($_POST['custom']);
```

But when I try and put $custom into my select statement I get an error.  I have tried a few different things here but can't seem to get the result.  I thought something similar to the below might work but it doesn't?  What is the best way to handle this?

```
$test = $pdo->query('Select col1, SUM(col2)*'$custom', SUM(col3), SUM(col3)*SUM(col2) from table group by col1');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is using a prepared statement to pass the parameter in.  However, you can't use prepared statement parameters in column lists, so you'll have to quote the value in instead.

```
$test = $pdo->query('
    Select 
        col1, 
        SUM(col2)*' . $pdo -> quote ($_POST ['custom']) . ', 
        SUM(col3), 
        SUM(col3)*SUM(col2) 
    from table 
    group by col1');
```

You'll have to also make sure that $_POST is numeric, because if it's blank or something you can't multiply by then the query will still fail.  You can do that like this.

```
$custom = $_POST ['custom'] * 1;
$test = $pdo->query('
    Select 
        col1, 
        SUM(col2)*' . $pdo -> quote ($custom) . ', 
        SUM(col3), 
        SUM(col3)*SUM(col2) 
    from table 
    group by col1');
```

Comment: Why can't you use prepared statement parameters in column lists ([it works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db7fe/1/2) directly in MySQL)?  Is it a PDO curiosity?

Comment: Also, in the latter example where you are certain that `$custom` is a numeric value (albeit I'd probably use `floatval()` instead of multiplying by 1), why bother with `$pdo->quote()`?

Comment: In general, you can't specify column names using a placeholder because it will just get quoted and turned into a string literal, causing an error when you execute it.  However, after further reflection, in this particular case I think you could use it to put your multiplier in.

Answer (score 1):

convert it into number as below and try this

```
$custom = $_POST ['custom'] * 1;
$test = $pdo->query('Select col1, SUM(col2)*' . $custom . ', SUM(col3), SUM(col3)*SUM(col2) from table group by col1');
```

Comment: why not use intval or floatval instead of *1 -- when dealing with possible SQL injection you really want to know if you're getting data this isn't exactly what you expect.